# Orbit Scenekit camera around specific node

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out how to get my SceneKit camera to orbit around a specific node in my game.

If I have a single node (a ship) and a camera in my scene everything works fine. If I add an additional node (a planet) the cameras pivot point appears to change from my ship to a space between my ship and planet.

Things I've tried:

- Setting a lookat constraint on my camera (set to the ship)
- Settingcamera position to my ship (it will move but the pivot point
  still seems to be between the two objects)
- Changing the cameras pivot point

  example:

  ```
  class TestSceneViewController: UIViewController, SCNSceneRendererDelegate {

  var scnView: SCNView = SCNView()
  var scnScene: SCNScene!
  var cameraNode: SCNNode!
  var ship: SCNNode!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      setupView()
      setupScene()
      setupCamera()
  ```

  ...

  ```
  func setupView() {
     // scnView = self.view as! SCNView

      // retrieve the SCNView
      scnView = SCNView(frame: view.frame)
      scnView.showsStatistics = true
      view.addSubview(scnView)

      scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
      scnView.defaultCameraController.interactionMode = .orbitTurntable
      scnView.defaultCameraController.inertiaEnabled = true

      scnView.delegate = self
      scnView.isPlaying = true
      scnView.loops = true
  }


   func setupScene () {
    scnScene = SCNScene()
    scnView.scene = scnScene

    let ships = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/simpleshuttle3.scn")

    ship = ships!.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true)
    ship?.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
    scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(ship!)

    let planets = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/sphere.scn")!
    if let planet = planets.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Ball", recursively: true){
         planet.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 40)
         scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(planet)
     }
   }

          func setupCamera() {
              cameraNode = SCNNode()
              cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
              cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: ship.position.x, y: ship.position.y, z: 80)
              cameraNode.camera?.motionBlurIntensity = 1.0
              cameraNode.camera?.automaticallyAdjustsZRange = true
              scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
      }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You are enabling the manual camera control.

`scnView.allowsCameraControl = true`

If you want to use e.g. `SCNLookAtConstraint` you have to disable that. Otherwise you have a conflict. The camera is not supposed to point at a certain position while simultaneously being rotated by the user.

If you want to stay with the default camera controller you can create an additional `SCNNode` as the parent for your planet and the ships. This parent node can now be moved so that the pivot point is at your desired position.

Comment: I added the parent node but moving it's pivot point doesn't give me what I expected (orbit around player ship). Still seems to have the same effect where the camera is orbiting a point between the ship and planet. Feels like the default camera has a setting where it's trying to always show both objects on screen or something...i'll look into creating my own as well. Pretty frustrating apple made it look like they solved a bunch of camera issues in their 2017 WWDC video.